# Refreshing secrets in Azure Functions using key vault reference

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault, c#-6.0

I have been using key vault reference A LOT over the years. Usually, I have been running Y1 Dynamic plans, but lately tasks require me to use S1 Standard App Service Plans.

I often need to update secrets in key vaults. When doing that, these rules apply: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#rotation - gist: On app restart, secrets are updated.

On several occasions I have experienced, that this is not the case! Am I the only one?

I have tried portal stop-wait-start and PowerShell Restart-AzFunctionApp, but the old variables prevail (checked in kudo and code fails).

Is there something else I need to restart to update the variables, when running S1 Standard functions with VNet integration?

Comment: It's that time again. I had to update a secret used in the function code - same MO: Secret is stored in Key Vault with a reference to the secret in the Key Vault. Several reboots does not update the environment variable to reflect the new secret value.

Comment: As @kaarel comments, running the deployment pipeline (both infrastructure and code) updated the environment variables. It would be really great with an easier way to do this

Comment: for clarity: It does not refresh on restarts. It refreshes when there is a change in configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this similar problem with changing keys.

- You either delete and build the app again (ci/cd), which is stupid
- I have manually deleted the Application settings reference from the configurations and then added it back, this has worked for me.

Comment: You could add more detail on why this happens and how to delete the application settings reference from the configurations